# Erasing a merge commit by hard resetting back to a commit that was gained in the merge?

Tags: git, github, merge, commit

My history before the merge looked like `A -> B -> C`

The branch I was merging looked like `A -> B -> C -> D -> E`, i.e. the branch has the same history as mine but has two new commits

I simply wanted those two commits, so I merged that branch into mine. After the merge, my branch looked like  `A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F`, where F is a merge commit.

I didn't want the merge commit F in my history, so I hard reset back to commit E...

Wait, what?

I removed a merge commit by hard resetting back to a commit that was gained in the merge commit...? Is that possible? I thought the merge commit itself is the thing that applies whatever new commits you gained from merging, so if you undid the merge commit (as I did) then you'd lose everything that the merge commit did, i.e. you'd lose all the commits you gained by merging.

Is that just not how merge commits work?

Comment: Why would you lose all the commits? They still exist without the merge commit.

Comment: Consider using git log with the graph option and you will see the history is not linear.

Comment: You didn't gain the E commit as part of the merge. That commit already existed. What you did was basically an elaborate way to reproduce what a `git merge BRANCH --ff` would've done.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Hmm, the thing is these were two branches on different forks (when I merged I had to select "merge across forks"). Is your answer still the same even then?

Comment: Forks are just clones. "Merge across a fork" just means "copy the commits from clone A to clone B as needed, then merge". So this is exactly the same as if it were all in a single repository, because copying commits from clone A to clone B makes the clones sufficiently alike so that all the action now happens in clone B as if it had all happened in clone B all along. That is, the identity of a *commit* is retained, regardless of which *repository* it's in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your repo's got `merge.ff` set `false`, or if you specify `--no-ff` on the merge some other way, Git will record a merge even when, as here, it's not strictly necessary.

You got to

```
A---B---C-------F    master
         \     /
          D---E
```

where the `F` content is identical to the `E` content.  There's times when you want this, for instance in a production history it's often convenient to record what actually got put into production as a series of merges like this, anybody who knows the convention can see that `D` was never put in production, it's part of a series.

So when you `git reset --hard` to `E`, you removed the record of the merge without altering the content at all, and the resulting history is exactly what a fast-forward merge would have gotten you.